# Google PubSub decrease attempts to delivery a message by push

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a Cloud Run service that subscribes to a PubSub topic using HTTP Push.

When my service returns HTTP 400, PubSub keeps trying forever. How can I decrease the delivery attempts and add a time between each attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your PubSub subscription, you can use 2 features:

- Dead Letter Topic
- Retry policy

[image]

Dead letter topic, after a number of tries (mini 5 tries), ack the message publish it in another topic. Like that, after a certain number of tries, the message is no longer pushed to your app.

*You can choose to listen, or not, the dead letter topic. By default, if there isn't subscription on the dead letter topic, the messages are deleted.*

The retry policy add exponential backoff between each tries.